# Why am I getting an errror when making an iOS native call to a javascript function with JSValue as a parameter?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, hybrid-mobile-app, javascriptcore, jsvalue

I am trying to call a javascript function by passing in `JSValue` as a parameter.

```
func callJavascriptFunction(value: JSValue, context: JSContext) {
    context.evaluateScript("functionInJavascript(\(value))")
}
```

I got this error message:

> JS Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Object'. Expected either
>   a closing ']' or a ',' following an array element.

Could anyone please help me solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Just got it working:

```
context.objectForKeyedSubscript("functionInJavascript").callWithArguments([value])
```